# How to create a parquet file from CSV with our own schema in pyarrow

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, parquet, pyarrow

I tried converting parquet source files into csv and the output csv into parquet again.there was a type mismatch in the values according to the schema when comparing original parquet and the generated one.Is there any way to create the parquet file with exactly the same schema as the original source?

This is the code:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa

schema_full=pq.read_schema(source_path+'\\'+onlyfiles[0])
full_df = pd.concat(pd.read_parquet(source_path+'\\'+parquet_file) for 
parquet_file in onlyfiles)
full_df.to_csv(target_path+'\\'+target_filename+'.csv', index=False)

Target_df = pd.read_csv(target_path+'\\'+target_filename+'.csv',index=False)
target_table=pa.Table.from_pandas(Target_df)
pa.Table.cast(target_table,schema_full)
print(target_table)
```

Below is the error i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\Documents\Python Scripts\parq_ascii_pyarrow.py", line 31, in <module>
    pa.Table.cast(target_table,schema_full)
  File "pyarrow\table.pxi", line 1390, in itercolumns
  File "pyarrow\table.pxi", line 410, in pyarrow.lib.Column.cast
  File "pyarrow\error.pxi", line 89, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: No cast implemented from double to decimal(8, 2)
```